# Quadruple integral from probability problem

Tags: probability, integration, multiple-integral, beta-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral which arises from a probability problem
$$\iiiint\limits_{\Omega} (1-e^{-(u+v+w)})^{n-4}e^{-(u+v+w)-(n-3)x}d\Omega,$$ where $\Omega$ is the region defined by $0<u\leq v\leq w\leq x<\infty$ and $n$ is an integer $\geq 4$.

An answer using Beta function $B(x,y)=\int_{0}^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ would be fine (and nice to obtain).

I managed to calculate the analogous integral (albeit multiplied by a constant) in two or three dimensions and got a linear combination of Beta functions, namely
$$n(n-1)\iint\limits_{0<u\leq v<\infty} (1-e^{-u})^{n-2}e^{-u-(n-1)v}dudv=nB(n-1,n)$$
quite straightforwardly and
$$n(n-1)(n-2)\iiint\limits_{V} (1-e^{-(u+v)})^{n-3}e^{-(u+v)-(n-2)w}dV 
$$ where $V=0<u\leq v\leq w<\infty$, which equals $$\frac{n(n-1)}{n-2}\left(\frac{1}{2} B\left(n-1,\frac{n-2}{2}\right)-B\left(n-1,n-2\right) \right)$$ (calculated by changing the order of integration).

However, I must say I can't quite do the same with this integral in 4D and any help is appreciated. Even math software like Maple has let me down (it had already on lower dimensions however).

Comment: Have you tried expanding the first factor using the binomial theorem, integrating termwise and then resolving the sums using partial fractions? That might be a bit of work but should give you a closed form.

Comment: Try $y=u+v+w$ with $dy=du$.  Then change the order of integration among $y,v,w$ so that $y$ is outermost.  The integrals over $v$ and $w$ can be evaluated leaving a double integral over $y$ and $x$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I have a hard time seeing how this would impact our new bounds, and how this change of variable would not affect $v$ and $w$ so that we can integrate them first. Perhaps you could explicit the new bounds we would obtain under your suggestion, so that I can try to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Order changes:  first $(y,v)$ omitting other term.  $\int_0^wdv\int_{v+w}^{2v+w}dy=\int_w^{2w}dy\int_{\frac{y-w}{2}}^{y-w}dv+\int_{2w}^{3w}dy\int_{\frac{y-w}{2}}^wdv=\int_w^{2w}\frac{y-w}{2}dy+\int_{2w}^{3w}\frac{3w-y}{2}dy$
Next interchange $(y,w)$ we have $\int_0^xdw\int_w^{2w}\frac{y-w}{2}dy=\int_0^xdy\int_\frac{y}{2}^y\frac{y-w}{2}dw+\int_x^{2x}dy\int_\frac{y}{2}^x\frac{y-w}{2}dw$

and $\int_0^xdw\int_{2w}^{3w}\frac{3w-y}{2}dy=\int_0^{2x}dy\int_\frac{y}{3}^\frac{y}{2}\frac{3w-y}{2}dw+\int_{2x}^{3x}dy\int_\frac{y}{3}^x\frac{3w-y}{2}dw$.
I'll leave the $w$ integrations (4 terms) to you.

Comment: Post script:  Interchange x and y leads to a an integral, where the integration over x can be carried out explicitly, resulting in an integral in one variable (y).